# update stock_status from instock to outofstock where stock=0

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

When getting a new website designed, the web developer made a mistake when reading in the product database and now a load of products with `stock = 0` are showing as `stock_status = instock`.

I need to change the `stock_status` to out of stock.

```
Table = wp-postmeta

meta_key = stock_status AND meta_value = (either instock or outofstock)

meta_key = stock AND meta_value = 0
```

I am trying to do this using PHPMyAdmin query

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and the table definition as a `create table` statement. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the answer and it goes like this:

```
UPDATE `YOURDATABASE`.`wp_postmeta`
SET `meta_value` = 'outofstock'
WHERE `post_id` IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT `post_id` FROM 
`YOURDATABASE`.`wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_stock'
AND `meta_value` = 0) AS custom)  AND `meta_key` = '_stock_status';
```

Tested and works :)
If you want to try it out on a single entry then add an individual `post_id` after `meta_value=0` such as `AND`post_id`= ??`